# Función recursiva python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmos

Estoy empezando a aprender python y tengo el siguiente problema:

Desarrolle una función que reciba un número natural n (suponiendo que n > 1) y que construya
y retorne un vector v de tamaño n tal que v<sub>k</sub> = v<sub>k−1</sub>/3 + π para k = 2, . . . , n y siendo que v1 = 2

Tengo algo como esto en mi solución:

```
import math 

n = 4
c = math.pi

def vector (n):
    if n == 1:
        return 2
    else: 
        return (n-1)/3+c

 vector(4)
```

Pero quería saber silo estoy interpretando bien.

Alguien tiene idea?

Answer (score 0):

Una función para crear un vector como descrito, empezará con una lista `[2]` y añade los siguientes elementes uno por uno. Nota que `v[-1]` es la forma para indicar el último elemento de una lista en Python.

```py
import math

n = 4
c = math.pi

def vector(n):
    v = [2]
    for i in range(1, n):
        v.append(v[-1]/3 + c)
    return v

print(vector(4))
```

Escribirlo como una función recursiva es posible, pero un poco elegante:

```py
import math

n = 4
c = math.pi

def vector(n):
    if n == 1:
        return [2]
    elif n > 1:
        v = vector(n-1)
        v.append(v[-1]/3 + c)
        return v

print(vector(4))
```

Si, al contrario, solo quiere el último elemento del vector, una función recursiva tiene un poco más de sentido:

```py
import math

n = 4
c = math.pi

def vector_ultimo_elemento(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 2
    elif n > 1:
        return vector_ultimo_elemento(n-1)/3 + c

print(vector_ultimo_elemento(4))
```